# I have a difficult definition. Want to ask: "what do you understand from this definition?"

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

But it will probably be closed I guess, since there is no specific question.

It will really help me if someone gives an answer containing a visual explanation, or an example, or an important particular case which generalizes to my definition, or etc.

I mean, if my definition is the formal definition of Riemann integral, I need answers like:

- it just calculates the area under the curve
- put rectangles under and above the curve, and make their width smaller. Your definition is the limit of the sum of area of that rectangles.
- if your function is constant then the answer is always (b-a).f(x)

So, how should I ask the question in a way that it will not be closed?

Comment: It's possible to ask questions about the intuition behind mathematical concepts, they don't always get closed (in fact I don't think they get closed more than usual). If you want to see example of good such questions, you can look at questions using the tag [tag:intuition].

Comment: I think as long as you are careful to explain what it is you don't understand about the definition you have been given, and tag it appropriately, it should be fine.

Comment: I suggest avoiding "what do you..." in the question, it makes it look like an opinion poll. If you want an example, or visual interpretation, ask for those. Ask what *you* want to know, not what others think.

Comment: I think that questions of this type have been asked in the past. Try [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22intuition+behind%22+site:math.stackexchange.com) or [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=intuition+definition+site:math.stackexchange.com) or simply the tag ([tag:intuition]) to see some such questions.

Comment: be careful to include a definition in your question. mjust asking "what is an Riemann integral" without the definition of what YOU understand about is is probably not a good idea , many terms have more than one definittion that should all give thesame item , but are not equivalent  in feelings or problems they trow up.

Comment: One could also phrase it like this: "From which problems does <> arise as a solution?" or "What problems motivated mathematicians to invent <>?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I'd ask such a question is specifically ask about the meaning of the definition in the explicit terms that you're looking for, i.e., "The definition of the Riemann integral is yadda yadda yadda; can someone explain this to me in geometric/visual/graphical terms?"

This is, in my opinion, a reasonable request, as long as you stay on topic. By defining the specific terms/parameters you'd like the answer in, your question can't be considered unspecific or vague.

If people vote to close your question, you might want to make sure that there haven't been any similar questions posed in the past, and that the tags you chose are relevant.

If, for whatever reason, people incorrectly vote to close your question, you could always ask it in chat.